# What is a finite area of a curve.

Tags: definite-integrals, curves

I am trying to find the area between two curves for this problem.

> $$y = \frac{1}{x}$$
>
> $$y=\frac{1}{x^2}$$
>
> $$x = 2$$

I have not learned how to solve infinite regions and was told to look for the area between $x= 2$ and $x=1$ because it is the finite region and they intersect at $x=1$. However I do not know why this area is considered finite. Can someone please explain why it is considered a finite region and how to identify them?

Comment: It should be clear $\int_1^2 1/x-1/x^2 dx$ is finite since the integrand is bounded on the interval $[1,2]$

Comment: @Golden_Ratio I wasn't given value x=1 for the question, somebody explained that I need to look for the area between x=1 and x=2.

Comment: So what were you asked in the original question if you were not given the bounds?

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough in my question, but I was only given the bound for x=2 and I had to draw the graphs to figure out what the other bound was.

Comment: To find where they intersect, you just need to solve $1/x=1/x^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generaly, if $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, then the area between $f$ and $g$ is
$$
Area=\int_{a}^{b}(g(x)-f(x))dx
$$
In our case
$$
Area=\int_{1}^{2}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)dx
=\left[\ln(x)+\frac{1}{x}\right]_{1}^{2}
=\ln 2-\frac{1}{2}
$$

Comment: Hi @boaz, I wasn't give the bound x=1 inside the textbook, when I asked somebody else about it they said to calculate it for x=1 and it was because it was a finite area, since I haven't learned about infinite integrals. Could you explain why x=1 is the other bound?